# Hamming numbers in python

Tags: python, hamming-numbers

I came across a question in codewars which asked to find the *n*th smallest Hamming Number. Basically the number can only have 2, 3, and/or 5 as factors.  Below is the code that I made for it.

```
def hamming(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    elif n == 3:
        return 3
    elif n == 5:
        return 5
    else:
        count = 1
        i = 2
        while count < n:
            if check(i):
                count += 1
            i += 1

        return i

def check(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    elif n == 3:
        return True
    elif n == 5:
        return True
    else:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return check(n / 2)
        elif n % 3 == 0:
            return check(n / 3)
        elif n % 5 == 0:
            return check(n / 5)
        else:
            return False
```

But it's not giving the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Since your presumably doing codewars to learn more about coding, it doesn't really help you to give you the answers.

Try just running:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, hamming(i))
```

and look at the output.  You can easily figure out what the first ten outputs are supposed to be.  Figure out why you're not getting that.  What is it giving 5 as an answer twice, and then skipping 6?

Comment: Thank you for this. It's been a while since this, I'll try and figure it out.